# Resolve optional dependencies in Java 9 Module System

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Java 9 module system support optional dependencies through `requires static my.module`. The dependency is only used at compile-time, and it won't be resolved at run-time even if it is in the module-path. So, how could optional dependencies be resolved?

1. **A solution:** Add flag `--add-modules my.module`. 
   **Question:** is the dependency added to the root dependency or is it added as root?
2. Is it possible to have a direct `requires` to avoid using `add-modules` flag?

Comment: The reason you need the --add-modules is because nobody requires my.module so it's not resolved. If you find yourself in this situation then it's likely that refactoring the split to use services will make this a lot cleaner. That is, turn my.module into a service provider module that provides an implementation of some service type. Your main module will use that service type and so will locate the implementation in my.module when my.module is deployed.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks for your comment. Do you mean that I can use providers in a way to add optional modules? So, when a module is needed at run-time, it can be resolved with `ServiceLoader`.

Comment: @AlanBateman Also, if we use services, it means that the dependency isn't optional anymore. Am I right?

Comment: If you migrate it to services then it's no longer a dependency. If the service provider will the implementation is deployed then ServiceLoader will locate it. If you work through an example then you should find it's not too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A solution: Add flag --add-modules my.module. Question: is the
>   dependency added to the root dependency or is it added as root?

The module added using the flag `--add-modules` is added to the default set of root modules and the module graph and resolved at runtime for execution since the dependency on the module was defined to be optional during the compile time.

> Is it possible to have a direct requires to avoid using add-modules
>   flag?

Yes, you can have a direct `requires` as well for such dependencies and make sure module is added to the module graph non-optionally, but that is a matter of design when you consider optional vs non-optional dependencies for your project.

The `requires static` basically provides a means to specify a module dependence that is mandatory at compile time but optional at runtime, for use with libraries that are not strictly necessary but can be leveraged if present at runtime.